# Console Java application running from the command line

Tags: java, model-view-controller, command-line

I am trying to write an application with the launch from the command line. I would like to implement all the features of the OOP, in particular the MVC design pattern. Honestly, I have never done such a thing before (I created applications interactively or using JavaFX GUI). I created the Person class, using the stream API, parsed the input string. I created an interface containing a method that should have different implementations .. But, as it seems to me, I'm not going the right way. Please help in further development. Here is what I have for today:

Model class:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 9005793181629487010L;

private static AtomicInteger nextID = new AtomicInteger(0);

private int id;
private String name;
private String surname;
private String age;
private String address;

public Person(int id, String name, String surname, String age, String address) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
}

public Person(String name, String surname, String age, String address) {
    this(nextID.getAndIncrement(), name, surname, age, address);
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\n\nID: " + getId() + "\nName: " + getName() + "\nSurname: " + getSurname() + "\nAge: " + getAge() + "\nAddress: " + getAddress();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Person person = (Person) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, person.name) &&
            Objects.equals(surname, person.surname) &&
            Objects.equals(age, person.age) &&
            Objects.equals(address, person.address);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, surname, age, address);
}}
```

The class of processing the file in which the entire info is saved:

```
public class DataFile {
private File file;
private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

public DataFile(String fileName) {
    this.file = new File(fileName);
}

public void save(Person person) {
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true))) {
        writer.write(person.getName()+ "\r\n" + person.getSurname() + "\r\n" + person.getAge() + "\r\n" + person.getAddress() + "\r\n\r\n");
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    loadAll();
    writeToJson();
}

private void loadAll() {
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String name;
        while((name = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Person person = new Person(name, reader.readLine(), reader.readLine(), reader.readLine());
            people.add(person);
            reader.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e + "\n\nA new file 'db.txt' will be created.\n");
    }
}

private void writeToJson(){
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data_file.json"))) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        bw.write(gson.toJson(people));
        bw.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}}
```

An interface containing a method that processes each command:

```
public interface Command {
void execute(Map<String, String> options);}
```

Implementation of the "add to file" command:

```
public class AddCommand implements Command {

@Override
public void execute(Map<String, String> params) {
    Person person = new Person(params.get("name"), params.get("surname"), params.get("age"), params.get("address"));
    System.out.println(person.toString() + "\n");
    params.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("flag: %s - value: %s\n", k, v));
    DataFile file = new DataFile("db.txt");
    file.save(person);
}}
```

Well, the main class of the program:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Arrays.stream(args).forEach(System.out::println);
    Map<String, String> params = new Main().parse(args);
    AddCommand add = new AddCommand();
    add.execute(params);
}

private Map<String, String> parse(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2){
        if (i + 1 < args.length){
            parameters.put(args[i], args[i + 1]);
        }
    }
    return parameters;
}}
```

It all works, but, I can’t figure out how to implement search-replace, delete, and so on. Maybe I’m sorting out the input string incorrectly .. And I don’t understand how I need to process commands like add, update, find, view, etc. Probably it was necessary to parse the string with "global" and "local" parameters, i.e. in the interface, set the method arguments to execute (Map  globalOptions, Map  localOptions) ... Where the first Map is the file and its name, and the second Map is the name, last name, age, etc. But maybe I'm wrong. Help is needed!

Comment: Honestly, I really don't know what you're trying to ask. You've posted a **lot** of code, and you seem to be asking several different questions, without any context for any of them. Please try to remember that we do not have any prior experience with whatever you've written.

Comment: I also don't know what you're asking. And for CLI command/arguments parsing, there  are already well-known libraries like Jopt (simple), Commons CLI, etc

Comment: I would like help in how to process the command present in the string ... For example, the string: file ="simple.txt" add name --Alex surname --John age --18 address --str,,Noname, or string file ="simple.txt" update name --Alex surname --John age --18 address --str,,Noname, or file ="simple.txt" delete name --Alex surname --John age --18 address --str,,Noname, etc.

Comment: as I said, use a library for that, e.g. JOptsimple or similar